# Round the summary row in phpgrid

Tags: php, jqgrid, grid

I have a grid with a summaryrow which shows the averages of the group like this:

```
$dg->set_group_properties('year');
$dg->set_group_summary('amount','avg');
```

The output will add a summary row with the average purchase amount per customer for a given year (group).

Now I want to round the average in the summary row to 1 digit (ie `467.075` should be `467.1`), but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2):

This helped me:
https://phpgrid.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/215864-fix-group-sum-floating-decimal-issue

```
<?php 
... 
$dg->set_group_summary('amount','###mysum###'); 
... 
?>

<script> 
function mysum(val, name, record) 
{ 
// this will round sum to 2 decimal 
return parseFloat(parseFloat(val||0) + parseFloat((record[name]||0))).toFixed(2); 
} 
</script>
```